# Windows detects all flash drive file systems as RAW

Tags: windows-7, filesystems, usb-flash-drive, fat32, raw

My computer that's running Windows 7 detects all flash drive file systems as RAW, and thus shows an error message to format them as soon as they're plugged in.

I tested all the flash drives in other computers and have no problem and their file system is FAT32.

How can I fix this issue?

Comment: Hope you've tested all USB front and back ports? Suggestion: Disconnect all non-input USB devices, then in Device Manager try deleting all USB root hubs and controllers (best to do it with a PS/2 keyboard or via Remote Desktop, because your USB mouse and KB will stop working). Reboot and Windows will reinstall them. See if that helps. Also run `sfc /scannow` from an admin command prompt. If this is a hardware issue though you'll need to get a new motherboard or perhaps an add-on PCI-E card that supplies USB ports.